# How add custom header in each response (GET/POST rest based services) c#

Tags: c#, web-services, rest

How to add custom header in each response (`GET/POST` REST-based services) using C#

I am trying this, but it doesn't working:

```
IMindMapRESTSrvc.CreateGroup(Group group) 
{
    try
    {
        Creategroup creategroup = new Creategroup();
        Header header = new Header();
        header = bl.readheader();
        if (bl.IsValidUser(header))
        {
            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingRequest.Headers.Add("SESSIONID", header.SESSIONID);
        }
        else
        {
            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingRequest.Headers.Add("SESSIONID", "");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't you mean OutgoingResponse instead of OutgoingRequest?